# get src link from img tag nested under div tag with BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, discord, discord.py

**Goal:**
Extracting an image link from [this](https://brawlstats.com/profile/9J8LRGQU2) website in order to reuse the link in my code. I'm essentially trying to retrieve the img src value of the image.

The image I'm trying to get is this blue logo

[image: marked with a circle]

It's nested as:

```
<div class="mo25VS9slOfRz6jng3WTf">
    <img src="https://cdn.brawlstats.com/ranked-ranks/ranked_ranks_l_10.png" class="DPUFH-EhiGBBrkki4Gsaf">
    <div class="_3lMfMVxY-knKo2dnVHMCWG _21sSMvccqXG6cJU-5FNqzv" style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:18px;">
    </div><!----></div>
```

I want to get the "https://cdn.brawlstats.com/ranked-ranks/ranked_ranks_l_10.png" link stored in a variable.

**Attempts:**

Latest version of the code I tried:

```
async def league_rank(interaction: discord.Interaction, tag: str):
    url = "https://brawlstats.com/profile/" + tag.upper()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
    all_imgs = [img["src"] for img in soup.select(".mo25VS9slOfRz6jng3WTf img")]
    print(all_imgs)
```

It returns a blank response.

**Reasons for creating the question:**
I tried several methods found on other Stackoverflow questions as well, none of which seem to work. How do I get the src of this image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add valid `headers`, otherwise you'd get `internal server error` in the `HTML`.

For example, put the `headers` and use a `CSS` selector:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:107.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/107.0",
    "Host": "brawlstats.com",
    "ReReferer": "https://brawlstats.com/profile/9J8LRGQU2",
}

url = "https://brawlstats.com/profile/RYJUGR8L"
image = (
    BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text, "lxml")
    .select_one("img[src*='ranked_ranks_l']")["src"]
)
print(image)
```

Output:

```
https://cdn.brawlstats.com/ranked-ranks/ranked_ranks_l_10.png
```

Comment: I noticed that you're using `if "1_10` in" to check the img src directly. Since this is a videogame stats website, this image in particular will change based on the player's rank from l_1 all the way to l_19 (19 ranks). How would the code be changed in order to get the img src regardless of which rank it is?

Comment: Can you share a URL that the `l_10` value changes?

Comment: so, in the case of this guy (https://brawlstats.com/profile/RYJUGR8L), his img src ends with l_19.

Comment: @ZaidHussain I've updated the answer. Should work with either url.

Comment: are headers explained in the BS4 docs? That's a new thing for me.

Comment: No they're not. You can read more about `headers` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers).

Comment: running this throws the error `FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?`

Comment: install `lxml` with `pip install lxml`